# Python Console with Logging

Tags: python, input, printing, console, sticky

I'm in the process of rewriting a server program, and I want to add into it a simple console input.

At the moment, it just serves data and prints out one or two lines for each thing it does, as a descriptive measure for anyone watching/debugging.

What I want is to have a "sticky" input bar that is always at the bottom, above which my debug prints appear, so that I can enter commands at any point while the program is printing. This would look a bit like:

```
...
[88.88.88.88] Handling Connection on Port 11452
[12.12.12.12] Received Data
[44.44.44.44] Sending Disconnect Sequence
>>>Enter Data Here at Any Time
```

Ideally, this would be done without curses as this would complicate matters. I feel like I must be missing a simple solution.

Thanks in Advance,

Freddy.

Comment: I believe you want to run a background process (similar to calling an executable with a `&` in linux) using `subprocess.Popen`. I don't have a more explicit solution, but thought the comment worth including so you might have an easier time searching for an answer.

Comment: In what way would curses "complicate matters"? Without it, or another similarly-complex library, you have to handle terminal control sequences, etc. manually. Does that sound easier?

Comment: I'm not sure how a subprocess could be related or useful in this scenario... I don't want a separate program to open.

Comment: I just didn't want to use curses as I was sure there must be a simpler way.

Comment: What do you expect the simpler way to look like? If you want the line to be "sticky", you have to draw a line at a particular screen position, place the input cursor, scroll the rest of the screen without touching that line, etc. The code to do those things with `curses` isn't particularly complicated.

Comment: Drawing a line at the bottom of a dynamic screen seems to be challenging. It's not that I specifically hate curses it's just that I am sure someone will have an easier solution.

Comment: Would a higher-level library like `urwid` count as an easier solution? Because otherwise, I'm pretty sure you're wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a slightly higher-level library than `curses`, there are a few, like [`urwid`](http://excess.org/urwid/docs/tutorial/) (although of course they don't come with Python, and have to be installed).

If you really want to avoid a windowing library, I suppose you could run the server under [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html), configured with an input bar and a rest-of-the-window, and give the server the two virtual TTYs instead of normal input… but that would be a lot more work, not less.

If you want to go lower level, you can always use `termios`, search `termcap`, and manually write control sequences to manually take care of scrolling everything but the last line, moving the input cursor, and so on. But that's going to be even more work.

And of course there's always the super-hacky possibility: For every output, and after every input, "redraw" the whole screen by spamming a few hundred blank lines, re-writing the output, and writing the input line. This will look terrible, and not work in a variety of edge cases, but it does avoid any kind of windowing.

---

However, I think there's a much better way to solve this problem.

You've already got a server. Why not just serve the console API on another "control" port (maybe just on localhost) instead of on the stdin/stdout/tty? That will work even if the server is, e.g., running as a daemon. And it means you can use your favorite fancy Telnet or similar client as a console, instead of having to write something from scratch.